# Ag-grid react data not refreshing rowData

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

On one of our react website we implemented ag-grid and have row grouping and sorting based on business rules.
We have a condition that on click of button we need to refresh the grid data.
We made the implementation and that after API response we update grid  rowData (managed from state variable). 
Sporadically for some users we are facing issue that grid data didn't get updated (new rows/ group are not added to grid) 
Can you please enlighten on how should we proceed with this kind of sporadically occuring issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Grid maintains its state internally but in your case it looks like React is handling the state for you so to achieve that you can implement `deltaRowDataMode={true}` along `getRowNodeId={data => data.id}` callback.
For more information you can visit official docs:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-redux-integration-pt1/#delta-updates